# Session is lost on javascript redirect

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have two methods in my class:

```
class Foo {
   public first() {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['a'] = 'a';
      $this->renderView('index.html');
   }
   public second() {
      var_dump($_SESSION); die();
   }
}
```

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.location = "/foo/second";
</script>
```

The problem is that in `second()` method session variable is empty. Why is that so?

Comment: If you think an answer has helped you find your solution, please mark it as the answer for your question. If it does not, reply to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You did not start the session.

```
public function second() {
   session_start();
   var_dump($_SESSION); die();
}
```